# Tengo problemas con pip en mac osx

Tags: python, shell, terminal, pip

Estoy tratando instalar una librería para python 2.7 en mac osx con pip de la siguiente forma:

```
python -m pip install pyttsx
```

y el shell retornó:
`/usr/bin/python: No module named pip`

Entonces intenté probar que si existía con python [así](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JO138.png)

y mostró que si existía pip, entonces ¿Dónde esta pip?
¿Cómo arreglo esto? ¿Cómo puedo instalar esa librería?

Comment: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: no funciona tampoco con pip3 
[Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Puedes instalarlo con el siguiente comando `sudo python -m ensurepip`, lo que se me hace extraño es que por alguna razón tienes instalado python3 según tu imagen. ¿Instalaste python3 con algún manejador de paquetes o de que forma?

Comment: no no use nada raro arrojo esto  OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip'

Comment: ¿Lo hiciste con sudo? ¿Que versión de macOS utilizas?

Comment: funciono con sudo gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que la versión de python que viene instalada en macOS no viene con `pip`.

Si necesitas `pip` para trabajar con la versión 2.7 de python que viene incluida con macOS tienes que instarlo ejecutando el siguiente comando

```
sudo python -m ensurepip
```

Answer (score 1):

Instalación Pip

```
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py  
python get-pip.py --user  
export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH >> ~/.bash_profile   
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Espero te ayude.